# Matplotlib Histograms

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot my data (1D array) into an histogram with Matplotlib.

```py
num_bins = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(
    cluster_1bo,
    num_bins,
    density=False,
    facecolor='g',
    alpha=0.75
)
```

[image: output]

The problem is that I would like to divide the height of the bin for a given number, say 100, in order to get the average value and plot it in the histogram.

Is it possible to do it with `.hist` without counting how much times a certain number appears, then divide that number of 100 and plotting?

Comment: Not sure I follow. Instead of, let's say, 2000 on the y-axis - you'd like to see the number 20?

Comment: Do you want to divide the frequency of occurrence before you even measure it ? OR do you want to achieve a probability density? Not sure what you are trying to achieve. Strictly following what you wrote, you can use hist to get the heights. Divide it with n and use a bar() for a new plot.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could try this:

```
np.random.seed(10)
values= np.random.randint(0,100,1000)
#change y_axis values
fig, ax =plt.subplots()
ax.hist(values,50)
y_values = ax.get_yticks()#get y_values
ax.set_yticklabels(['{:}'.format(x/100)for x in y_values]) #divide each y value by 100
plt.show()
```